# Div not wrapping link correctly

Tags: html, css

How can I make the link to stay inside the div element, and not extend above and below it? Looks like it has something to do with padding which is not accounted for and the div thinks the link is just as tall as the text is.

Is there a way around it?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/na6B3/)

Code:

```
div {
    background-color: yellow;   
    margin-top: 20px;
}
a {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: blue;    
}
a:link {
    color: white;   
}

<div><a href="#">Link button</a></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
div {
    background-color: yellow;   
    margin-top: 20px;
}
a {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: blue; 
    display:inline-block    
}
a:link {
    color: white;   
}
```

Comment: This stretches the link to the div's lenght, which is not desirable. I just want the div to wrap the link completely from top and bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Add the padding to your div, not your link.

```
div {
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: yellow;   
 margin-top: 20px;
}
a {
border: 1px solid black;
background-color: blue;
}
a:link {
 color: white;   
}
```

Comment: I want to have padding between link text and its border, not in the div.

Comment: Then you have no other option then to add 
  display:block; to your link

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using padding on your anchor it needs to have display:block set.

Please see my jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/na6B3/13/).

```
div {
  background-color: yellow;   
  margin-top: 20px;
}
a {
  padding: 10px;
  display:block; //Added this
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: blue;    
}
a:link {
  color: white;   
}
```

Comment: This stretches the link to the div's lenght, which is not desirable. I just want the div to wrap the link completely from top and bottom.